# Integrating a C# console application in LabView

Tags: c#, labview

I have a C# console application that i want to integrate to LabView.

I read on the internet that it should be converted to a DLL file in order for it to be called upon by LabView.

The thing is that i don't know how to do that as there should be no main function, only the classes.

Here's the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the message to hash :");
        text = Console.Read().ToString();
        string computedshaHash = ComputeSHA1Hash(text.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(computedshaHash);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string ComputeSHA1Hash(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] textbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create()) 
        {
            byte[] computeHash = sha1.ComputeHash(textbytes);
            for (int i = 0; i < computeHash.Length; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(computeHash[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated =)

I should also note that i suck with C#, i merely found this on the net.

Thanks

Comment: basically you could create a Library which will create a Class file for you also you will not be able to launch it from the debugger directly, you would add that assembly / .cs file to your project as a reference, and you would duplicate the same code that you would in the main section, add that to the Constructor of that Lib class and create your methods as either Internal or public, there are plenty tutorials online on how to convert class file to a dll / library

Comment: If your code above is only a simplified example, or you want to build your own DLL as a learning exercise, that's fine, but if all you really want is to compute an SHA-1 hash in LabVIEW then there are libraries already available - see [here](https://lavag.org/topic/14889-cr-encryption/) or search ni.com for `sha-1`.